# Implementing a class for the functionality of theme managing :

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a class library silverlight project , so there is no app xaml in it. I am defining all my styles in one ResourceDictionary xaml (so that every style I defined inside my project will be global).

Now if I want to apply a style to a custom control which don't have its xaml... only .cs.

Then I can do it with the help of some class which will have the functionality to apply the style defined in the resource dictionary.

But I don't know how this functionality will be achieved, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.